# Concatenar valor de variable dentro de una función

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función de javqascript que funciona perfectamente, es esta:

```js
function listFiles() {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'pageSize': 1000,
          'q': "'0B5pqU4vxIuqcU1BDaVdIcHRFQVk' in parents",
          BLA BLA BLA...
```

Ahora quiero cambiar un poco esta función y me interesa que reciba por parámetro un valor. Este valor debo sustituirlo por la cadena de texto que hasta ahora estaba escribiendo a pelo ( '0B5pqU4vxIuqcU1BDaVdIcHRFQVk'). De modo que quedaría algo así:

```js
function listFilesFolder(idCarpeta){
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'pageSize': 1000,
          'q': idCarpeta+" in parents",
          BLA BLA BLA...
```

Está claro que algo estoy haciendo mal, ya que esto no funciona. He probado también de esta manera, con el mismo resultado:

```js
function listFilesFolder(idCarpeta){
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'pageSize': 1000,
          'q': "idCarpeta in parents",
```

Ya me he cerciorado de que el valor que recibo por parámetro es del tipo string, pero está claro que hago algo mal. ¿Alguien que me pueda echar una mano?. Gracias!

Comment: Has intentado usar template  literals que serian asi ``${idCarpeta} in parents`` dentro de las comillas '' pero inclinadas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el primer caso, el que funciona, "q" tiene un valor final de "'0B5pqU4vxIuqcU1BDaVdIcHRFQVk' in parents". En el segundo caso, si idCarpeta fuera 0B5pqU4vxIuqcU1BDaVdIcHRFQVk, "q" tendria un valor de "0B5pqU4vxIuqcU1BDaVdIcHRFQVk in parents" sin comillas. Para que te funcione debes utilizar interpolacion de string, quedaria asi: 
`'${idCarpeta}' in parents`, esto envuelto en backquotes .

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un template literal string para formar el valor de q:

```
  const listFilesFolder = idCarpeta => {
    return {
      pageSize: 1000,
      q: `'${idCarpeta}' in in parents`
    };
  };

  const NAME = listFilesFolder("0B5pqU4vxIuqcU1BDaVdIcHRFQVk");
```

[Código de ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/template-literal-string-u8jqd?file=/src/App.js)